# Enums management in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, enums

I need help or some guidance/best practice on how to manage enums in Objective-C. I am coming from C++/C# land where I can explicitly call an enum like:

```
mycharacter.type = EnumType.enumValue;
```

THere is no conflict since I call the enum Type, then the enum value. In Obj-C, enums are created as typedefs, so they all have to be indexed with unique numbers otherwise there will be problems at runtime. I was initially creating my enums in their respective class with no starting value, so all enums were initially with zero. I spent a good 2-3 hours trying to troubleshoot some simple collision detection in Cocos2D/Box2D and afterwards found it was due to enum not having unique values, so collision was not happening properly.

If there is a way to call enums just like in C#/C++, please let me know, otherwise please point me to some knowledgeabase or best practice docs since I am not a C developer.

Please advise.

Comment: Can you be a little more clear about "enum not having unique values"? You mean two different `enum`s? A single `enum` will always have different values for each of its constituents. How did two separate enums conflict?

Comment: I'm not quite following. Enum types in C++ are basically the same as in C except that they automatically typedef.

Comment: Hi Josh Caswell, Chuck, I have several enums in my Obj-C proj, with no initial values, so they all by default start with zero. I created an enum: typedef enum { LEFT, RIGHT, TOP, BOTTOM } WallTags; For some reason in my collision detection method's switch statement would not recognize LEFT, until I did LEFT=101. Then it detected it in the switch statement. I am not sure if two enums can conflict but my assumption is as best practice that all enums should have at least a unique starting index so there are no conflicts with global values or other hidden #defines

Comment: @badboy11 to avoid collisions in C, we tend to prefix the values, e.g.: `typedef enum { WallTags_LEFT, WallTags_RIGHT, WallTags_TOP, WallTags_BOTTOM } WallTags;` or in C++ use a strongly typed enum or enum declared within a class scope.

Comment: Yes, I have been prefixing my enum values to be unique and meaningful so it can be easily associated with which object they belong to and their purpose. I just quickly typed some code since comments are limited in characters here. This is how I actually created  the Wall Enum to be used in SetUserData in box2d. typedef enum { WALL_BOTTOM=101, WALL_RIGHT, WALL_TOP, WALL_LEFT } WallFixtureTag;

Answer (score 3):

Objective-C is a superset of C. You have C-style enums which are effectively C++ enums declared in the global namespace:

```
enum {
 MyConstant = 1
};
```

And an example from AppKit:

```
enum {
    NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual = -1,
    NSLayoutRelationEqual = 0,
    NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual = 1,
};
typedef NSInteger NSLayoutRelation;
```

enum values are just static integers -- you cannot message them as you would an object (also true in C++), nor can you ask them their name or scope. You can cast/convert to other numbers or specify their width (an extension in ObjC).

> due to enum not having unique values, so collision was not happening properly

If you don't assign the values, then they will be automatically valued one greater than their preceding enum's value.

So if you want a more flexible object, you may want to consider making a class or using a collection. C enums are very useful, and very basic.

Note that you can use C++ in Objective-C in the same translation -- it is called Objective-C++.

Comment: Thank you Justin for the feedback. I am a bit tempted in using a collection, but I personally like enums. They are very powerful and handy. I tried creating a C++ style enum, but I still have to assign it just like C-style typedef enums. I'll just try to assign a unique starting value to all my enums so I won't have to painfully troubleshoot issues like the one I had today. My codebase is not big, but it would sure become painful if there were a lot more going on.

Comment: @badboy11 or you can use stricter C++ enums to prevent some errors, or you could consider a structure which might use a second field to distinguish the enum type separately. verifying enums do not overlap manually is error prone. you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

They are C enums. 
They are not objects. 
They work well for lightweight named option arguments and bit field mask options, as well as in C switch-case conditionals. 
You will find them used in this way in Objective-C. 
There should be no collision as they are just typedefs for const integers. 
To use them effectively in Xcode be sure to meaningfully prefix and name the enum and members. This gives you useful code completion.

Also see the useful macros NS_ENUM and NS_OPTION 
NSHipster blog has a good send up.